# Divide the sentence into 2 parts in R

Tags: r

This is text file around (20 txt file)

In each text file

Suhas - Politics
Pope Francis has highlighted the plight of refugees from Syria and Iraq and condemned extremism at the start of a key visit to Turkey.

Sachin - Sports
Defending champion PV Sindhu continued her good run and entered the semifinals of the women's singles competition after beating China's Han Li in three games at the Macau Open Grand Prix Gold on Friday

Suhas - Politics
The United States lodged an appeal on Friday to challenge a World Trade Organization ruling that said it had failed to bring its meat labelling laws into line with global trade rules.
Sachin - Sports
After four games without a goal, Mumbai City FC would look to end their goal drought and get back to winning ways when they take on Delhi Dynamos at the Jawaharlal Nehru Stadium on Friday.

This will keeps on going.

Question :
We neet to copy all Suhas data in one txt file and Sachin data in another txt file. we need to separate the two data in 2 txt file.

I have showed for 1 txt but need to do for (20 txt file). I mean 20 txt for Suhas and 20 txt for Sachin.

Need your help to build R code

Comment: DO you have only `Suhas` and `Sachine` data in each of the `txt` files or have other ID's too mingled in between?

Comment: No Ids in the data but there are other names as well which we need to ignore

Answer (score 0):

Here, I created two `files` that start with `Sports` i.e `Sports1.txt`, `Sports2.txt`

```
files <- list.files(pattern='^Sports\\d')
files
#[1] "Sports1.txt" "Sports2.txt"
lst <- lapply(files, function(x) {x1 <- readLines(x)
                              x2 <- x1[x1!='']
                           indSuh <- grep("^Suhas", x2)
                          indSach <- grep("^Sach", x2)
                         list(x2[indSuh], x2[indSach])})


Map(function(i, x, y){nm2 <- paste(y, i, '.txt', sep='')
    lapply(seq_along(x), function(j) write.table(x[[j]],
               file=nm2[j]))},seq_along(lst), lst, list(nm1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using two packages I maintain, **qdap** and **qdapTools**.  I just added a function to **qdapTool** `loc_split` that will work nicely for this but you'll need the development version.

First getting the packages to get started:

```
 library(devtools)
 install_github("trinker/qdapTools")
 library(qdap); library(qdapTools)
```

Now the code:

```
## path of folder with txt files
fileloc <- "mydata"

## Read in Files
fls <- dir(fileloc)
input <- file.path(fileloc , fls[tools::file_ext(fls) == "txt"])
m <- unlist(lapply(input, readLines))

## Determine location of blank lines   
locs <- grep("^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*-\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$", m)

## split text on locations of group name with hyphen 
out1 <- loc_split(m, locs)

## extract the meta data
meta <- sapply(out1, "[", 1)

## create a data.frame of text and meta data
dat <- data.frame(
    setNames(colSplit(meta, "-"), c("group", "topic")),
    text = sapply(out1, function(x) unbag(x[-1])), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

## split on the group variable (could do for topic or topic & group)
out2 <- split(dat[["text"]], dat[["group"]])

## Write out the lines using cat and the Map function
Map(function(x, y) {
    cat(paste(x, collapse="\n\n"), file=sprintf("%s.txt", y))
}, out2, names(out2))
```

Note that this first makes a data frame with meta data about each text that looks like:

```
    group     topic                                             text
1  Suhas   Politics Pope Francis has highlighted the plight of re...
2 Sachin     Sports Defending champion PV Sindhu continued her go...
3  Suhas   Politics The United States lodged an appeal on Friday ...
```

As this can be useful.